# Python: How to round 123 to 100 instead of 100.0?

Tags: python, rounding

```
>>> round(123,-2)
100.0
>>>
```

How to round it to 100 instead of 100.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int(round(123,-2))
```

The [int function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) can be used to ***convert a string or number to a plain integer***.

Answer (score 2):

you can just throw it in `int`:

```
In [1]: int(round(123, -2))
Out[1]: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `int(100.0)` to convert to `100` in python 2.x and in python3.x, its just works

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, ...
>>>
>>> round(123,-2)
100
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression : (\d+)\..* to match the entire thing and extract only the integer part.